# Apache2 Ubuntu16 laravel don't work

Tags: php, apache, laravel, ubuntu, apache2

When I'm trying to get the site by ip, I'm getting:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The document root of your apache has to point to the public folder

from the docs of laravel:

**Public Directory**

*After installing Laravel, you should configure your web server's document / web root to be the  public directory. The index.php in this directory serves as the front controller for all HTTP requests entering your application.*

see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation